# Low water pressure issue

Tags: water-pressure

I have replaced both PRV and expansion tank and still have an issue with water pressure when one or more taps are used.  Any ideas for my next step.

Comment: Have you checked for particles in your aerators and cartridges?

Comment: Do you have a pressure gauge available?  It would be helpful to know if the pressure is dropping before or after the PRV or only at the tap.